# p5js resizeCanvas is not a function on resize

Tags: reactjs, p5.js

I'm using react-p5. I'm trying to make the canvas resize when the window size changes. I try this do this by adding a resize event listener and calling a function everytime the browser gets resized.

Code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", windowResized);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", windowResized);
});

// Canvas Setup
const setup = (p5, canvasParentRef) => {
    p5.createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight).parent(canvasParentRef)
}

function windowResized(p5) {
    p5.resizeCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}


// Main App
<Sketch setup={setup} draw={draw}  />
```

The problem is that when I resize the browser I get: Uncaught TypeError: p5.resizeCanvas is not a function at windowResized. I read on a different question that says that other p5 functions are only available to run after the `setup()` but this is my first time using p5js so I'm not sure if that's the problem. thanks

Comment: Don't quote me on this, but I think that p5.js functions can only be called from setup() or from draw().

Comment: Wait ur right. How could I fix this though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to assign `p5` to a component state in the `setup` function then you can use later on. The draft idea would look like:

```js
const App = () => {
    const [p5, setP5] = useState();

    // Just register event as mounted
    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("resize", windowResized);
             
        return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", windowResized);
    }, []);
    
    const setup = (p5, canvasParentRef) => {
        // set to state
        setP5(p5)
        p5.createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight).parent(canvasParentRef)
    }
    
    function windowResized() {
        // keep in mind, `p5` can be `undefined`
        // so check it before using
        if (p5) {
            p5.resizeCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        }        
    }
     
    return <Sketch setup={setup} draw={draw}  />
}
```